# Failures are not collected in dynamic created test suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, test-suite, test-runner

I have a jar file that I reflect from it test classes (junit test).

I created TestSuite instance and added the tests to it.

In order to check my code, I've tried to add only one example test class to the test suite.

```
TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(ExampleTest.class));
```

Then I called suite.run() in order to run the test:

```
TestResult result = new TestResult();
suite.run(result);
```

The  problem is that when the test is done, the failures list that should be in result is empty.

```
Enumeration<TestFailure> failures = result.failures(); // = empty list
```

How can I get the failures using testSuite? If I use JUnitCore.runclasses , I do get the failures list but it can't be used with an instance of TestSuite, which I have to use since I get the test classes as input.

**Edit-1:**

If it is possible to create a Class that extends TestSuite and add classes to the suite dynamically, it will be good for my needs to.
Any suggestion will be great.

**Edit-2:**

From more searching in the web, I saw there us a difference between a [failure](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/Failure.html) and a [testFailure](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestFailure.html). How can I fail a test with testFailure and not a failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging, I found out that the TestResult object did catch the failures but reported them as Errors (Assertion Errors).
I also found out that TestResult.errors() returned an enumerator of TestFailure. Each TestFailure contain information about the thrown exception, so I can distinguish now between errors and failures by checking which of the errors are Assertion Errors and which are not.